# I have an issue with animating this circle in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am using JavaFX and AnimationTimer to get a circle to move to a random location triggered by clicking the circle. The issue I am seeing is that the circle will not go toward the the top-right or bottom-right of the screen, I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;

public class MovingCircle extends Application {
    double WIDTH = 800;
    double HEIGHT = WIDTH;

    class TheCircle extends Circle {
        public TheCircle(){
            super();
            setFill(Color.GREEN);
            setCenterX(WIDTH / 2);setCenterY(HEIGHT / 2);
            setRadius(50);
            setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                double newX = random(50, HEIGHT - 50); double newY = random(50, WIDTH - 50);
                move(newX, newY);
            });
        }
        void move(double newX, double newY){
            double xVelocity;
            double yVelocity;
            if (newX == getCenterX()){
                xVelocity = 0;
            }else {
                xVelocity = getCenterX() < newX ? 1 : -1;
            }
            if (newY == getCenterY()){
                yVelocity = 0;
            }else {
                yVelocity = getCenterY() < newY ? 1 : -1;
            }
            AnimationTimer h = new AnimationTimer() {
                @Override
                public void handle(long l) {
                    setCenterY(getCenterX() + xVelocity);
                    setCenterX(getCenterY() + yVelocity);
                    //System.out.println(getCenterX() + ", " + getCenterY() + " ; " + newX + ", " + newY);
                    if (getCenterX() == newX && getCenterY() == newY){
                        this.stop();
                    }
                }
            };
            System.out.println("begin!");
            h.start();
        }
    }

    public void start(Stage stage){
        Pane root = new Pane();
        TheCircle mover = new TheCircle();
        root.getChildren().add(mover);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    double random(double min, double max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
}
```

It seems that if I force the `xVelocity` and `yVelocity` to animate the circle toward those areas the circle either just stalls or the window freezes up. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don’t know for sure if this is the cause of your problem, but you have your calls to `setCenterY` and `setCenterX` switched.  You should be passing `getCenterX() + xVelocity` to setCenterX, and vice versa.

Comment: Also, there is no need to `+1` for generating value in `random()`.`random(50.0, 51.0)` would give `(0 to 51-50+1) + 50` which would give `50` to `52`.

Comment: Thank you, but I also have an issue with stopping the animation, too. Know any way to get it to stop?

Comment: Keep a reference to the `AnimationTimer`; add a mechanism (e.g. a button) which invokes `AnimationTimer#stop()`.

Comment: Also, every time you call `move` you're creating a _new_ `AnimationTimer`, starting it, and then not keeping any references to it. An `AnimationTimer` will continue to execute even if you don't keep any references to it. In other words, the more you call `move` the more timers you'll have running simultaneously.